# Query MySQL to echo the value of a column based on the page's url

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page setup to get the last part of a url; i.e.:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
echo 'The current page name is ' . '"' . $page . '"';
```

This returns, for example:

> The current page name is "Concord Naval Weapons Station"

Concord Naval Weapons Station being the last part of the url:

```
http://www.andsoforth.com/shortRedirect.php?page=Concord%20Naval%20Weapons%20Station
```

What I need is for this page to forward the user to:

```
http://www.andsoforth.com/reports.php?page=concord
```

`concord` being in a column titled `shortname` while `Concord Naval Weapons Station` is set in the same row as `longname`.

Just to recap: when the user hits the page

```
http://www.andsoforth.com/shortRedirect.php?page=Concord%20Naval%20Weapons%20Station
```

the page needs to query the table `sites` and exchange the value of url+`longname` for url+`shortname` and redirect the user to that page.

I have no idea how to do this. Any advice or tips on where I can even begin to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Advice or tips? More context is needed. You haven't even hinted at what kind of MySQL layer you're using. Hopefully it's a framework like [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) or [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). Hopefully it's **NOT** `mysql_query`.

Comment: Yes, the only thing I've ever used is mysql_query. Would it be easier to use another framework? If so, can you point me in a direction that might help me find what I'm looking for? Thanks :)

Comment: I think you are searching for URL redirection.  Its done in this way,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection

Comment: @FirmView You're right that I need to re-direct, but my problem is in feeding the page the url to re-direct to. I start with one url, say `/1.php?url=1`, and need the page to redirect me to `/2.php?url=2` but the 2nd url can only be populated with whatever value is in a database. Querying the database and returning a result is where I'm stuck. I can do the re-direct part, though. Thanks :)

Comment: SELECT shortname FROM sites WHERE longname="$longname" -> you will get the shortnme and use header('Location: $shortname'); exit(); prepend whatever url to longname and shortname to it

Comment: Thanks for the code, FirmView! I modified it some, but this was what I went with: $page = $_GET["page"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT shortname FROM sites WHERE longname='$page'") 
        or die("Something broke! " . mysql_error());  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $shortname = '../reports.php?page=' . $row['shortname'];
    header('Location: ' . $shortname); exit();
}    ... if you can create an answer for the question that follows your logic, I'll select yours as the answer to this question. Thanks again! :)

Comment: New applications should not be using `mysql_query` as it's a dangerous relic from the 1990s. Unless you use it exactly as designed, you will expose yourself to to severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php). It's worth the time to read up on how to use either `mysqli` or PDO and use proper SQL placeholders to avoid problems like this. Your examples are **full** of serious SQL issues. Variables like `$page` **MUST** be escaped.

Comment: @user1661045 You're welcome, while is not necessary i think, you can check if(mysql_no_rows($query)>0).  As there will be only one short name and only one longname for the sites.

Comment: @tadman, While I certainly appreciate the sentiment of what you're saying, that the code laid out above is not where it should be, I don't find your comment to be particularly useful. Essentially all you've said is that I should junk everything I've done and start over--with what: you haven't said. The fact is that no sensitive information should ever be even remotely accessible from the front-end of any website, ever. And to this end I completely agree. I can, however, assure you that my site has no holes for the leakage of any pertinent, much less sensitive, information. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again, FirmView. Much obliged.

Comment: Flipping something from `mysql_query` to `mysqli` might be tedious at times but it is by no means difficult. The sooner you stop using `mysql_query`, the better off you will be. Using SQL placeholders is absolutely essential no matter the environment, protected or otherwise. You will make a mistake and it will introduce a bug if you're not *perfectly* careful with `mysql_query`. That's a risk you shouldn't be taking, especially when there are much better alternatives. There's a reason `mysql_query` is in the process of being phased out from PHP entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a SELECT query in a MySQL database to find WHERE longname = Concord Naval Weapons Station and then echo the result. This is a rather inefficient way to go about doing this, with more information we could maybe give you a better answer.

Comment: @ Number1SuperGuy, thanks so much for the response. Let's say I do this as a query, ie: SELECT * FROM sites WHERE longname = '$page' ... How does this return the shortname?

Comment: @user1661045 you should look into using prepared statements (using something like http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of doing `... longname = '$page'` which is a security risk (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: The SQL Injection attack is a great point, Patrick Q. And it should certainly be noted that these codes have some major security flaws in certain contexts. As for my specific needs, I hold no important information in my MySQL database; only the names of the sites, long and short, their corresponding ids, and the descriptions of the sites themselves. I will definitely be looking into stopping SQL Injections, though. If only for good measure. Thanks so much!